# how to display indiviudal test names from a nunit result xml file in the nunit-results.exe generated html report

Tags: c#, html, nunit

I have run nunit-console on my tests and generated the result.xml file. Then I used nunit-results.exe to generate html report.
How ever the report doesnt show any unit test method names.
I need to know if there is any option in nunit-results.exe to display the test method names in html report or is there any tool to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem
Created a customised version of nunit-results that displays the indiviudal test names
Thanks to Charlie Pool(https://launchpad.net/~charlie.poole) for making the source available